# jQuery, Make elements scroll at different speeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im trying to figure out how all of this parrallax scrolling works, nothing massive just subtle elements and im picking apart dave gamache's website and playing with it to see first hand.

I cant seem to make my inner title lose opacity as the window is scrolled however. Nor make the background image scroll at all.

Ive created a fiddle to show you what im working with, I think its something to do with my windowScroll var only im unsure, any helps greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/jzmQJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the scroll event and put the code that you have written to implement the parallax effect inside the event handler.

As it is the code that modifies the position of `$artHeaderInner` and `$artHeader` only runs once when the `ready` event is fired. To achieve the effect you want you need that code to run each time the scroll position changes.

This might get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/LtrPV/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a JavaScript library such as Skrollr.js.

You will have a perfect control of your animations and the timing.

Check out these two tutorials to help you get started:

- [Simple parallax scrolling tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
- [How to create a parallax scrolling website](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/)